# Htpasswd also for root directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, password-protection, .htpasswd

I tried to set password to directory.
This is my htaccess

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Nothing to see"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/test/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</IfModule>
```

It's work, the folder test request password but  also the main URL request.
Domain.com/test - request password
Domain.com/ - request password

I don't want to set password for the main directory (domain.com/)
How can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do it for a specific file do the following:

```
<Files /example>
AuthName "Nothing to see"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/test/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Putting your file name instead of '`example`'. Don't forget to set the `AuthUserFile` to the correct directory for your username and password. However, I have used the file directory from your above example :)